# How to properly get an array from jInput?

Tags: jinput

Maybe it's weary eyes, but I am unable to retrieve a posted array from jInput:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$test1 = $jinput->get('Itemid');
$test2 = $jinput->get("filter");
$test3 = $jinput->get("filter['subjects']");
```

`$test1` successfully retrieves the Itemid, but various ways of retrieving 'filter' only ever results in an *empty* array.

```
JInput Object
(
    [options:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [filter:protected] => JFilterInput Object
        (
            [tagsArray] => Array
                (
                )

            [attrArray] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [option] => com_xyz
            [view] => titles
            [Itemid] => 241
            [filter] => Array
                (
                    [subjects] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 6
                        )
                )
            [limit] => 25
            [limitstart] => 0
```

I don't mind feeling stupid for an oversight at this point, I'm just tired of fighting with it.  Any assistance is appreciated. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate / similar http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/5210/159

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$app        = JFactory::getApplication();
$jinput     = $app->input;
$filter     = $jinput->getVar('filter',array());
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: "Try this" answers on StackExchange sites are low value because they do very little to educate future researchers.  If you are able to expand on your answer to explain how your snippet works and why it is recommended, then please do so.  If it is too basic to describe, perhaps offer some resource/documentation links which spell things out.  Please always post answers with the intent to educate.

Answer (score 3):

I misread or misunderstood the documentation of `$jinput->getArray()`.  I understood this to return a subset of the input variables, as specified in an array of the variables you're interested in.  While this may be true, it will also return *all* input variable if an empty array is supplied:

```
$allfields = $jinput->getArray(array())
```

Comment: The answer doesn't address the actual problem of OP. OP wants to get a `posted array` not `array of all posted variables`. Your answer fetches the latter.

Comment: As the OP, I have to differ - I added this answer a courtesy of what I actually used to get what I described in the question.

Comment: I totally missed the fact that you were the OP, isn't that comedy :D

Answer (score 2):

Just been messing around with this a little.

Try adding a blank default value and [filter](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) type as arguments, like so:

```
$test2 = $jinput->get('filter', '', 'RAW');
```

Comment: This worked as well, but Piero beat you by 2 hours - no flowers for you this time, lol.

Comment: Pfff, any excuse not to get flowers lol

Comment: Don't worry, you'll get another chance....I have a new question coming shortly, lol