# Get multi checkbox values from jpost

Tags: joomla-3.x

I can get my form data using

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$jpost = $jinput->post; 
$feedback = $jpost->get('feedback', '', 'STRING');
```

But I have a group of checkboxes[] and can't seem to work out how to get the values submitted ...

Comment: [How to properly get an array from jInput?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/13648/12352)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the array filter.

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;    
$the_checked_vals = $jinput->post->get('checkboxfieldname', [], 'ARRAY');
```

https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Note that the values are not themselves filtered.

Comment: That worked. In hindsight, I am not sure what the struggle was.